# Login validation by using different tables having each email and password

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have 4 Tables student,tpo,admin,campany and each table having a coloumn email and password when user entered a values in login page i.e email text and password text then validation query check all tables and table having proper email and password can be login but if login credential belongs to tpo then tpo page can be appear and if login credential belong to student the student from can be appear other process can be done in same way.My form code is asp.net and backed is c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create procedure **pro_login** with this logic

```
Create Procedure pro_login
@Email varchar(max),
@Password varchar(max)
Begin
if exists(select userid from student where userid=@Email and password=@Password)
    Begin
    select 1
    End
    else if exists(select userid from tpo where userid=@Email and password=@Password)
    Begin
    select 2
    End
    else if exists(select userid from admin where userid=@Email and password=@Password)
    Begin
    select 3
    End
    else if exists(select userid from campany where userid=@Email and password=@Password)
    Begin
    select 4
    End
End
```

& write code in your.cs page

```
int res=Login(txtuser.text, txtpass.text);
if(res==1)
{
Response.Redirect("student.aspx");
}
else if(res==2)
{
Response.Redirect("tpo.aspx");
}
else if(res==3)
{
Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
}
else if(res==4)
{
Response.Redirect("campany.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you have a LogIn form that launch the other forms. You could make the Login method return an int depending on the table it found the user or a -1 if it does not found it

```
public static int LogIn(String email, String psw)
{
    if((from c in context.student
        where c.email==email and c.psw==psw
        select c).Any()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if((from c in context.tpo
        where c.email==email and c.psw==psw
        select c).Any()) {
        return 2;
    }
    if((from c in context.admin
        where c.email==email and c.psw==psw
        select c).Any()) {
        return 3;
    }
    if((from c in context.campany 
        where c.email==email and c.psw==psw
        select c).Any()) {
        return 4;
    }
    return -1   
}
```

That's made thinking that you have a class for all the querys, if not ypu can just launch whatever you want instead of returning.